# Using double pipes in onclick function - why would event be false?

Tags: javascript, delegation

I'm trying to understand how delegation works, and I found a good explanation [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation)

On the site, they include the code below. I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the use of the double pipes here. I did some research on StackOverflow and learned that double pipes are used to check if the first value is false (i.e. it's an `or`). 
However, in this case, the `onclick` was trigerred because there **clearly** was an event that happened.

So why would `event` ever be false? What's the point of using the double pipes?

```
table.onclick = function(event) {
  event = event || window.event
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement

  while(target != table) { // ( ** )
    if (target.nodeName == 'TD') { // ( * )
       toggleHighlight(target)
    }
    target = target.parentNode
  }
}
```

P.S. While I'm at it, is there any reason they omitted semicolons? Are they not necessary sometimes or is it just easier for them?

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html. All those articles about event handling are pretty good: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: `is there any reason they omitted semicolons?` Semicolons are optional in many places where they are inserted automatically. The rules are in [ECMAS-262 §7.9](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9). However, since the rules are a bit turgid, it's easier to manually insert semicolons (and it makes the code easier to read, in my view). Also, minifiers will likely totally mess up your code that doesn't have them (automatic insertion is a function of the script engine).

Answer (score 1):

The event object isn't always passed in to the click handler - IE has window.event instead
http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object

Answer (score 0):

With things like these, the normal assignment declaration usually has an or statement (`||`) to work across multiple browsers and allow the browser to assign whichever one is true. Here are some examples:

```
var webgl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
```

In this statement, I'm trying to access the WebGL context of the Canvas element. Now some browsers are older than others, and to support as many of them as I can, I request either the standard WebGL context, or the one called "experimental-webgl", which may be in old versions of Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Another example:

```
requestAnimFrame = return
    window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;
```

I'm trying to set up requestAnimationFrame here, a very fast and efficient way of doing stuff that is better than `setInterval();`. Again, I'm trying to make sure I support as many browsers as possible.

Last one from jQuery's source:

jQuery normalizes unstandardized properties across browsers. `event.which` normalizes the key code detection.

```
event.which = original.charCode != null ? original.charCode : original.keyCode;
```

In here, the check is to see whether charCode returns something, and if it doesn't, then that browser doesn't use that property, so JavaScript will try to access and assign the `keyCode` property to `event.which`.

Hopefully that gives you an idea of the purpose of `||` in an assignment declaration.

Comment: According to the OP's question, they already understood what `||` is used for: *"I did some research on StackOverflow and learned that double pipes are used to check if the first value is false (i.e. it's an or)"*. The question was in which case `event` would be falsy.

Comment: I still explained that.

Comment: Right after every example, supporting old browsers, any quirks they have, prefixed features.